# Comma separated number after specific substring in middle of string

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract a sequence of coma separated numbers after specific substring. When the substring is in the beginning of the string it works fine, but not when its in the middle.

The regex `'Port':\ .([0-9]+)` works fine with the example below to get the value `2`.

String example:

```
{'Port': '2', 'Array': '[0, 0]', 'Field': '[2,2]', 'foo': '[0, 0]' , 'bar': '[9, 9]'}
```

But i need to get Field value, I dont care if its '[2,2]' or 2,2 (string or number)

I tried various attempts with regex calculator, but couldnt find a solution to return the value after string in middle of the text. Any ideas? Please help. Thanks ahead, Nir

Comment: Hi, the example string is actually a value from dataframe column, i will apply this regex on the entire column, not all rows will have this field value and will remain nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the regex to be like this, not sure if thats what you want:

```
import re

string = "{'Port': '2', 'Array': '[0, 0]', 'Field': '[2,2]', 'foo': '[0, 0]' , 'bar': '[9, 9]'}"

output = re.findall(r"\'Field\'\: \'\[([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+)\]\'",string)

print(output)
```

output:

```
[('2', '2')]
```

if you want as a string:

```
output = str(output).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(' ','').replace('\'','')
print(output)
```

output:

```
2,2
```

EDIT:

If I got what you want, this might work, it will create a new dataframe with values with only a column called 'Field' and you can then append it to your own dataframe.

```
values = []

def get_values(mdict, values):
    pattern = r"\'Field\'\: \'\[([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+)\]\'"
    output = re.findall(pattern,mdict)
    output = str(output).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(' ','').replace('\'','')
    values.append(output)

# get_values(mdict, values)

for x in df['param']:
    get_values(str(x), values)

df_temp = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Field'])

df.append(df_temp)
```

Comment: Hi, both options result would be fine, but i need it on a dataframe, i try running it like this:  pattern=r"\'Field\'\: \'\[([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+)\]\'"
df['Field']=df['param'].str.extract(pattern, expand = True), this doesnt work, get error "Columns must be same length as key"

Comment: Hi, the problem with df is that the output is in 2 different columns, i changed the pattern to r"\'Field\'\: \'\[([0-9]+)\,[0-9]+\]\'" so now its working on df, but it still doesnt get any result, all column is nan

Comment: Hello, can you ellaborate more about this dataframe?
You could try this one if I actually understood what u want:
df['Field'] =  [re.findall(pattern, str(x)) for x in df['param']]

Comment: Hi, thanks for assist, this also doesnt work, " unhashable type: 'list'". the df taken from a postgre db, it contains multiple parameters in columns and additional grouped in a json like column, this is what i need to extract. i managed to get a number after specific substring that if it appears it will be first in the string, this doest work if the substring is not at the beginning, also now i need a value that is not a number only, i dont need to do calculations with it so string is enough

Comment: actually in the regex calculator this pattern works: \'Field\'\: (\'\[[0-9]\,[0-9]+\]\'), but on the df its still all nan

Comment: so there was a space between the digits that interrupted, this is the final pattern r"\'Field\'\: (\'\[[0-9]\, [0-9]+\]\')"

Comment: @nir Hello, I edited my answer and included a new part that could actually help you, just need to change my pattern with the one you sent now ->  r"\'Field\'\: (\'[[0-9]\, [0-9]+]\')"

Comment: Many thanks, actually the dataframe implementation i have is much more simple, df['Field']=df['param'].str.extract(pattern, expand = True), the output unique values are: array([nan, "'[2, 4]'", "'[3, 4]'", "'[1, 3]'", "'[5, 1]'", "'[3, 2]'",
       "'[2, 3]'", "'[0, 4]'", "'[1, 4]'", "'[3, 3]'", "'[2, 2]'",
       "'[4, 2]'", "'[4, 3]'", "'[0, 3]'", "'[0, 2]'", "'[1, 0]'",
       "'[0, 5]'", "'[5, 2]'", "'[5, 0]'", "'[4, 1]'"...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a `print()`ed Python dict; can you use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to bring it back into a dictionary?

```py
>>> import ast
>>> d = ast.literal_eval("""{'Port': '2', 'Array': '[0, 0]', 'Field': '[2,2]', 'foo': '[0, 0]' , 'bar': '[9, 9]'}""")
>>> d
{'Port': '2', 'Array': '[0, 0]', 'Field': '[2,2]', 'foo': '[0, 0]', 'bar': '[9, 9]'}
>>> d["Array"]
'[0, 0]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `2,2` for the `Field` value you can use a single capture group.

Note that you don't have to escape the `'` `:` `,` and `]`

```
'Field':\s+'\[([0-9]+,\s*[0-9]+)]'
```

- `'Field':` Match literally
- `\s+'\[` Match 1+ whitespace chars and `[`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[0-9]+,\s*[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits `,` optional whitespace chars and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `]'` Match literally

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6btHSw/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NI9nGO).

Example code

```
import re

pattern = r"'Field':\s+'\[([0-9]+,[0-9]+)]'"

s = "{'Port': '2', 'Array': '[0, 0]', 'Field': '[2,2]', 'foo': '[0, 0]' , 'bar': '[9, 9]'}"

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
2,2
```

---

If you want to get all the values where the fields are between single quotes you can use a conditional matching the `]` only when there is a `[`

```
'[^']+':\s+'(\[)?([0-9]+(?:,\s*[0-9]+)*)(?(1)\])'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hyNXYR/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/s3M0sn)

Then you can get the capture group 2 value.

Example:

```
import re

pattern = r"'[^']+':\s+'(\[)?([0-9]+(?:,\s*[0-9]+)*)(?(1)\])'"
s = "{'Port': '2', 'Array': '[0, 0]', 'Field': '[2,2]', 'foo': '[0, 0]' , 'bar': '[9, 9]'}"
matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(match.group(2))
```

Output

```
2
0, 0
2,2
0, 0
9, 9
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, but surprisingly its not working for me

Comment: @nir What do you get as a result? If you are using str.extract the first pattern should work right? `'Field':\s*'\[([0-9]+,\s*[0-9]+)]'`

Comment: @nir Can you update the question with the code you are using?